# Limit the output of jsch in Spring integration

Tags: log4j, spring-integration, slf4j, jsch

I am trying to limit the output of the com.jcraft.jsch package in my Spring Boot applicatoin. My application uses Spring Intgration and has a log4j.properties files defining the following log levels

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG
log4j.category.com.jcraft.jsch=ERROR
log4j.category.org.springframework.integration.file=ERROR
```

And still, I get a whole lot of INFO levelled messages from that package... I was expecting it to filter it out.
I followed the short description at the bottom of this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html)

Anyone with an idea as of why I still get flooded with comm. detail from jsch?

```
2015-05-21 11:12:55.750  INFO 10684 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : aes256-cbc is not available.
2015-05-21 11:12:55.750  INFO 10684 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : aes192-cbc is not available.
2015-05-21 11:12:55.750  INFO 10684 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
2015-05-21 11:12:55.770  INFO 10684 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
2015-05-21 11:12:55.770  INFO 10684 --- [ask-scheduler-1] com.jcraft.jsch                          : SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
```

I use log4j.1.2.17 and slf4j and my log4j.properties is located under src.main.resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my onw question, I had to do the following:

1. Exclude logback classic from my boot starter. Since it Spring Boot relies on Apache commons-logging and logback. In gradle it looks like so:

   `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration")
   {
      exclude module: "logback-classic"
   }`
2. Add a dependency to my Log lib of choice, log4j:

   `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j")`
3. Create a log4j.properies file inside src/main/java/resources/ where I state that jsch log level shoud be set to warning. **log4j.category.com.jcraft.jsch=WARN**

   `log4j.debug=true
   log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout, file
   log4j.category.com.jcraft.jsch=WARN
   log4j.category.org.springframework.integration.file=info`

   log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

   log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
   log4j.appender.file.File=C:\log4j-application.log
   log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
   log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
   log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add `logging.level.com.jcraft.jsch=WARN` to your `application.properties`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels.

Comment: This answer is correct for recent versions of Spring Boot + Spring Integration.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably picking up some other config on the classpath.

Run with `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to find out which file is being used (and how levels are set for each category.